# I need to create a path for java, I've put in the spot for my java folder in the value with the title path. But it still wont work (Windows)

Tags: java, path

I need to create a java path. HELP (Windows 7)

I have made a name called PATH in my advanced settings and I put the place where my java folder bin is in the value

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
```

but it still isn't working when I try to run what I need to?

It would be great if anyone has what I need but I cant figure out how to code it properly! Please help? :(

Comment: Did you put quotes around it? Is that actually the directory where the executable is? What *specifically* are you "trying to run", and how? What happens when it doesn't work? There's not enough information here to understand what you need (nor is it precisely on-topic yet).

Comment: Did you follow this? [How do I set or change the PATH system variable](http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: Are you sure you need the "Java" folder, not the "Java\bin" folder?
Anyway, you can avoid using spaces using Windows tilde substitution by using "C:\Progra~1\Java" (or "C:\Progra~1\Java\bin")

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in your advanced settings->Environment variables

```
  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
  PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
  CLASS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib
```

Refer in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html website to know more about setting path.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, don't create or use folder or file names with spaces in them. This will only cause  you many headaches down the road. Keep things simple.